# Routing in Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

Im working on a wordpress site where I'm using the Timber starter theme (link below). I cant get the routing to work properly. When i add a route to "functions.php" and try browse to that page i get 404. Cant figure out whats wrong.

Timber starter theme: https://github.com/timber/starter-theme

My code for routing (functions.php):

```
Routes::map('video', function(){
    Routes::load('video.php');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to [flush the rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)?

Comment: By flush, do you mean tho chmod the files? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with the files. It should work by simply go into Settings > Permalinks in the WP-admin. Just loading that page, WP flushes the rewrite rules.

Comment: Oh, i see. It dit not solve the problem tho.

Comment: Manage to sort it out by adding some rules to the .htaccess file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Be careful when manually editing RewriteRules in .htaccess when you use WordPress. Maybe you don’t need Timber’s routing at all. You can accomplish most of what you need by using the correct [Template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) only. Also see https://wphierarchy.com. Of course it depends on what `video` is on your website. Is it a custom post type, or a taxonomy, or something else?